# Linq group by giving incorrect statistics

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, group-by

I have a table from where I want to calculate statistics for below Statuses:

**Expected Output**:

```
Active = 12
OnHold = 10
Closed = 14
Filled = 15
Expired = 24
```

**Query 1:**

```
var statistics = (from j in context.Job
                  where j.CompanyID == 100 &&
                  {100,101,102,103, 104 }.Contains(j.StatusID) 
                 (j.ActiveDate == "0001-01-01" ? (j.CreationDate >= fromDate && j.CreationDate <= toDate):
                 (j.ActiveDate >= fromDate && j.fromDate <= today))
                 group j by new
                 {
                    j.StatusID
                 }
                 into g
                 select new
                 {
                    ActiveStats = g.Count(inner => (inner.StatusID == 100)),
                    OnHoldStats = g.Count(inner => (inner.StatusID == 101)),
                 }).FirstOrDefault();
```

I am getting incorrect statistics for "ActiveStats" and "OnHoldStats" for above query.

**Query 2:**

```
var statistics = (from j in context.Job
                  where j.CompanyID == 100 &&
                  {100,101,102,103, 104 }.Contains(j.StatusID) 
                 (j.ActiveDate == "0001-01-01" ? (j.CreationDate >= fromDate && j.CreationDate <= toDate):
                 (j.ActiveDate >= fromDate && j.fromDate <= today))
                 group j by 1 into g
                 into g
                 select new
                 {
                    ActiveStats = g.Count(inner => (inner.StatusID == 100)),
                    OnHoldStats = g.Count(inner => (inner.StatusID == 101)),
                 }).FirstOrDefault();
```

I am getting correct statistics for "ActiveStats" and "OnHoldStats" for above query.

I just don't understand why I am getting incorrect result for Query 1 and why correct for query 2?

Also, which query is more efficient in terms of performance?

I am keen to understand the difference between these two queries and which query I should choose in terms of efficiency and performance.

Comment: Which EF version?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Its 6.1.3

Comment: Try to replace `Count` with `Sum`:  `ctiveStats = g.Sum(inner => (inner.StatusID == 100 ? 1 : 0)`

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I did that too but still incorrect result for Query 1

Comment: Well, inner.StatusID == 100 means that you calculate Count only for one status. It is desired?

Comment: I am trying to calculate count for each of the statuses in 1 linq query. See  the expected output in my question

Comment: I've added answer, but if you need object with exact result by properties only your second query is correct.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Upvoted your answer for your kind efforts towards helping me but I wanted to understand whats the difference between 1st and 2nd query and how efficient 2nd query is as compared to Query 1?

Comment: Difference that after groping by `StatusID`, SQL Server will pass to `Count` only records for this StatusID. So you cannot count other statuses. `group by 1` is fake grouping which makes single record query with only aggregations.

Answer (score 2):

According to desired output, you have to run the following query:

```cs
var query = 
    from j in context.Job
    where j.CompanyID == 100 &&
        {100,101,102,103, 104 }.Contains(j.StatusID) 
        (j.ActiveDate == "0001-01-01" ? (j.CreationDate >= fromDate && j.CreationDate <= toDate):
        (j.ActiveDate >= fromDate && j.fromDate <= today))
    group j by new { j.StatusID } into g
    select new
    {
        StatusName = 
             j.Key.StatusID == 100 ? "Active" 
           : j.Key.StatusID == 101 ? "OnHold" 
           : j.Key.StatusID == 102 ? "Closed"
           : j.Key.StatusID == 103 ? "Filled"
           : "Expired",
        Count = g.Count()
    };

var statistics = query.ToList();
```